# Lost keystore password, but let Google Manage Signing Key

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I lost my locally created keystore file password, but when I uploaded the app to the Play Console, I choose the option "Manage Signing Key by Google". Does this mean:

- that whatever keystore I used locally to sign the app doesn't matter?
- if I upload a new version of my app (with same app id) to Google with a different signed keystore file, will Google recognize that the app is from me? And would the user's Android phone treat the app as the same app as before?

I followed the directions [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) to sign my Flutter app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've enrolled in Play Signing (i.e. "Manage Signing Key by Google"), then you can contact Google Play developer support and ask them for instructions on how to reset the upload key for your app. This will consist of creating a new keystore and sending them the new certificate (after you have proved your identity).

You will then need to change your signing configuration in your Flutter project to reference the new keystore.

After that, you'll be able to keep uploading updates of your app to the Play Console and your users will keep receiving updates as before.

The keystore you lost is what Google calls "upload key": it's only used to verify that what is uploaded effectively comes from you. But Google has a hold of the app signing key which it uses to re-sign the APK that are served to users.

The full documentation around Play Signing can be found here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Comment: Ok. So it seems you can change the upload key as many times as you want.